# GMC Missing value [shipping]

Tags: magento2.4

We are running a Magento ver. 2.4.6-p1 site. We have an auto fetch setup for our products so the GMC can see the latest XMl feed each week.

We have 157 products that get the "Missing value [shipping]" in the gmc.

These products are farm equipment, which when a person checks out on our site will get a message that says this items requires a Freight Quote. They can still check out, but have to call the office inorder to get the shipping. These are items that are oversized, but all other items (almost 9k) on our website uses are table rates and the GMC has no issues with them.

Has anybody ran into this before?

How do we clear the items so they can be seen on Google Shopping ads?

Thank you in advance for any help!